# t-sql Tree Join to Values to get a Sum of childless nodes limited to latest data

Tags: sql, sql-server, umbraco, common-table-expression

Looking to sum in SQL (MS 2008 r2) 2 relatively simple tables, I'm struggling though to find a way to make it work, almost there but I'd really appreciate some help from a SQL expert please :)

I join a tree type table to a collection of values, where we only retrieve the latest instance of the value (for each foreignkey x2) and each value has a creation date and we only want the latest value by the creation date. Also finally we only want to sum the values of those at the bottom of the tree (ie those without children). I read about CTE, and thought this was a good way to make it work but haven't done this before so still struggling a little bit to read what I've written :)

I have a tree table which is relatively simple called Nodes

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[parentID] [int] NOT NULL
```

The data in this table I am interested in is something like this. (Simple example in reality there would be between 1000-2000 records of up to perhaps 7 levels of nesting, typically just 3 or 4)  ID + ParentID is always unique.

```
ID      parentID
1077    1055
1110    1077
1103    1077
1104    1103
1105    1103
1111    1110
1112    1110
```

Then the other table Allocations that I want to join to this.

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[creation] [datetime] NULL,
[crewId] [int] NULL,
[mealId] [int] NULL,
[allocation] [int] NULL
```

It is the crewId that joins to the tree, and this is sent in as a paramter, so we would retrieve the sum of all children of 1077 for example. I want to include the sum of the childless values only. I want a sum for each value of the mealId. crewId + mealId + creation is always unique.

```
Id          creation                crewId      mealId      allocation
----------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2012-04-13 16:50:00.000 1111        1085        1
2           2012-04-13 16:55:00.000 1111        1085        3
3           2012-04-13 17:03:31.100 1111        1085        2
4           2012-04-18 22:35:21.790 1112        1085        1
5           2012-04-18 22:35:32.630 1112        1086        1
6           2012-04-18 22:35:42.473 1112        1087        1
7           2012-04-25 18:15:53.117 1111        1086        1
8           2012-04-25 19:11:46.227 1111        1085        1
9           2012-04-25 19:11:46.227 1110        1085        5
```

This is what I have so far,

```
declare  @crewId int
set @crewId = 1077

-- get total of allocated to childless children
;with 
Recurse as (
select 
  n.Id as DirectChildId
, n.Id
from umbracoNode n
where parentId = @crewId
union all
select
  b.DirectChildId
, n.Id
from umbracoNode n 
join Recurse b on b.Id = n.ParentId
)

select
  n.DirectChildId, mealId, sum(a.Allocation) as TotalAllocation
from Recurse n
left join Allocations a on n.Id = a.crewId
   and a.CrewId not in (select parentId from umbracoNode)
group by DirectChildId, mealId;
```

This almost works, but doesn't yet take account of getting the latest values.

The query I have that currently retrieves the latest version looks like this. But I can't work out how to combine them.

```
SELECT a.mealId, a.allocation
FROM Allocations AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Allocations AS a2
  ON (a2.crewId = @crewId and a.MealId = a2.MealId AND a2.creation < a2.creation)
WHERE a.crewId = @crewId and a2.crewId IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, and this was my answer:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[tegsGetTotalAllocated] 
(@crewId As Integer)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
;with q as (
SELECT n.id
FROM umbracoNode n
WHERE n.id = @crewId
UNION ALL
   SELECT n2.id
    FROM  umbracoNode n2
    JOIN q 
    ON n2.parentId = q.id
)

SELECT
  sum(a.allocation) as totalAllocated, a.mealId
FROM q
left join Allocation_Meal a on q.Id = a.crewId
   and a.CrewId not in (select parentId from umbracoNode)
where mealId is not null 
group by mealId
END
```

The main trick was to create a view that did the latest part. I'm not really clear what implications this has. Other than to give me a kind of virtual table that always contains the latest results. Is this always evaluated on every hit or is it cleverer than that?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Allocation_Meal]
AS
SELECT t1.mealId, t1.allocation, t1.crewId
FROM tegsAllocation AS t1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tegsAllocation AS t2
    ON (t2.crewId = t1.crewId and t1.MealId = t2.MealId AND t1.creation < t2.creation)
WHERE t2.crewId IS NULL;
```

Would really appreciate any thoughts or comments on if it could be more efficient :)
especially what indexes I should add to make this work better, or a good way to identify these :)

Comment: I would try obtaining latest crew/meal records differently, with `ROW_NUMBER()`, like this: `WITH ranked AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY crewId, MealId ORDER BY creation DESC) AS rnk FROM tegsAllocation) SELECT mealId, allocation, crewId FROM ranked WHERE rnk = 1`. I'm not sure if this method is better than your LEFT JOIN one, but I would definitely consider it worth testing.